# Dynamic casting with Delphi to access methods and properties

Tags: delphi, rtti, dynamic-cast

How can I achieve dynamic casting on a created object in order to have access to its methods or properties. Assuming that class of the object is very simple, with public methods and properties etc.

I have 3 units for 3 different frames that share common procedures.

```
unit frameTypeA;
type
  TfrmTypeA = class(TFrame)
    procedure doSomething(Sender: TObject);
end;

unit frameTypeB;
type
  TfrmTypeB = class(TFrame)
    procedure doSomething(Sender: TObject);
end;

unit frameTypeC;
type
  TfrmTypeC = class(TFrame)
    procedure doSomething(Sender: TObject);
end;
```

At some point in my code, I create these frames dynamically from all the above types. So I create some frames based on TfrmTypeA or frameTypeB or frameTypeC. Its not important for my question, but I keep all those created frame on a list.

```
// frame A
frame := frameTypeA.Create(Application);
// frame B
frame := frameTypeB.Create(Application);
// frame C
frame := frameTypeC.Create(Application);
```

I am trying to understand how to take advantage of RTTI or other Delphi mechanisms in order to achieve Dynamic Casting. If I want to execute a method with simple old-fashioned casting, I can do:

```
TfrmTypeA(tempFrame).doSomething;
```

And everything works fine. Delphi IDE knows about the method from that frame and I can easily use the cast to execute that method.

Now my question: if I get the class from the frame, how can I dynamically cast that class and use the method?

```
var
    tempClass: TClass;

begin
    tempClass:= tempFrame.GetClass; 
end
```

Is there a way to achieve something like this?

```
tempClass(tempFrame).DoSomething;
```

So that delphi will know in design time, that DoSomething is included on my class that I am casting?

Comment: Have you tried descending your A, B & C frames from an ancestor having a virtual `DoSomething` and overriding it in each of them?

Comment: You should perhaps do two things: derive the frame from a common ancestor frame type, and give that a **virtual abstract** method DoSomething. The descendant frames should implement and override that method in their own way. That is the classic way to perform (inheritance) polymorphism. Or your frames could implement a common interface with that method. Another way to get polymorphism.

Comment: I am not sure if it is going to work for me. Except from methods, I also want to have access on components that exists on the frame (common component between frames). The only way to access those component with the way you suggest, is maybe creating a virtual function that returns the desired component.

Comment: @Thersippos: then you'll have to cast to the actual type of the frame: `if X is TFrame1 then begin TFrame1(X).Button1.Caption := 'Boo!' end;`. There is no way around this, unless you have a common ancestor and common components on that ancestor. Or you can use FindComponent on the frame, but that is even more tedious, IMO.

Comment: You are confusing something that you can do at compile time (casting) with something that happens at runtime (dynamic class). When you hard cast, you are telling the compiler what to do. Calling a method dynamically is something that happens at runtime because the compiler doesn't know what class it's dealing with. You will need to use RTTI or something along those lines.

Comment: Expansion for RTTI is run time (as opposed to design time) type information. See [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Working_with_RTTI) for more information.